# In the BIOS the mouse is stuck

Tags: windows-8, motherboard, bios, mouse

I wanted to install SteamOS to try it, but I'm experiencing an issue.
Before the last bios update, everything worked fine. But after...
The mouse is stuck: when I try to move it, it moves for some milliseconds and then it returns back to the center of the screen. I already tried to use other mice, other USB ports, OTHER BIOS DRIVERS (newer/older). Nothing worked.
(Yes, I already removed the 3v battery to reset the bios).
I need to overclock, change some CPU settings and other things.
What shall I do?

The mouse WORKS FINE on W8.1
The problem is the bios.

Computer specs:

Motherboard: Asus z87-k
CPU: I7-4770K
RAM: 16GB DDR3 @ 1600MHz
2xSSD & 1xHDD formatted with NTFS
A not-working Fireware port PCI adapter

Comment: Can't you navigate through the BIOS setting using the keyboard?

Comment: +DavidPostill no :( i can navigate through the pages, but I can't use the keyboard when I open a menu (boot menu). For the menus, I need a mouse to select elements. The arrows, page UP/DOWN don't work. Also the Reset changes can't be selected using the keyboard :/

Comment: Really. you cant navigate the entire bios by using just keyboard? Thats news for me you know.

Comment: I can navigate but I can't select buttons like "save settings" and other things. But fortunately, I found a solution: unplug the joystick :/

Comment: You can use the TAB button to navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself!
When you have a problem, start searching from the most stupid things:
so, I **unplugged** my Joystick and my headset.
Result: the mouse works :/ xD

Comment: I just had the exact same problem. The solution was to unplug my Dualshock 4 (Playstation 4 controller) from the USB port while I'm using the BIOS.